# Android application getting stuck when swiping through Viewpager, and navigation drawer in marshmallow device

Tags: android, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer, swipe, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am using ViewPager inside my Navigation Drawer all are works fine in devices other than marshmallow devices. in marshmallow devices when i clicking toggle button or swiping the navigation drawer (in both direction) feel a stuck(glitch) in the flow, also when i swipe the viewpager into different tabs also found the stuckking. This was found only in marshmallow device. please help me,, thanks in advance....

this is my code

activity class

```
 public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    Toolbar toolbar;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container,new HomeViewPagerFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
        navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
               switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.home:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new HomeViewPagerFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
 }
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}
```

ViewPager fragment

```
public class HomeViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {


    ArrayList<Model> mArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
    Model model;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    HomeViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    public HomeViewPagerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_view_pager,container,false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);


// parsing and add datas into mArrayList


        viewPagerAdapter = new HomeViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),mArrayList);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(Credentials.homeTabSelected);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab){
                Credentials.homeTabSelected = tab.getPosition();
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**viewpager adapter**

```
public class HomeViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
ArrayList<Model> mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "tab1","tab2" };

    public HomeViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Model> arrayList) {

        super(fm);
        mArrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position==0) {
            return new HomeCentralFragment();
        }
        else {

            return HomeRecyclerFragment.newInstance(mArrayList);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabTitles.length;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

HomeCentralFragment

```
public class HomeCentralFragment extends Fragment {
    public HomeCentralFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_central,null);


       //my code is here(buttons, click events etc...)


        return rootView;
    }


}
```

**HomeRecyclerFragment**

```
public class HomeRecyclerFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public static ArrayList<Model> mArrayList =new ArrayList<>();
    Fragment fragment;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    public static HomeRecyclerFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Model> arrayList){
        HomeRecyclerFragment fragment = new HomeRecyclerFragment();
        mArrayList = arrayList;
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_recycler_view,null);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        //to make horizontal or vertical listview using recyclerview
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new HomeRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), mArrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

            });
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

                View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if(child != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                   Credentials.selectedPolititian = rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), PersonDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Class","HomeActivity");
                    intent.putExtra("array",mArrayList);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    getActivity().finish();

                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });



        return rootView;

    }
}
```

**HomeRecyclerAdapter**

```
public class HomeRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Model> profiles;
    Context mContext;

    public HomeRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> profile) {
        this.profiles = profile;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public HomeRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_fragment_home_recycler, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HomeRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.name.setText(profiles.get(i).getmName());
        int length= profiles.get(i).getmDepartment().size();
        int k;
        String res ="";
        for (k=0;k<length;k++){
            res = res + profiles.get(i).getmDepartment().get(k)+"\n";
        }
        viewHolder.department.setText(res);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return profiles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView name, department;
        //private ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            // imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.p_name);
            department = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.p_department);

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you attached views to your viewpager for each tab?

Comment: please share your Log else check this how to you use viewpager https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip and other http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Comment: here i add my code now, please refer and help me to solve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

check view fragments layout, avoid .jpeg images (use .png images)...
check the view pager with some simple fragments, if it work smoothly check the layout views..